# I have been experiencing this NOT ADirectory Error while running a code in Python

Tags: python, argv, python-os

The ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "images.py", line 11, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'images.py'
```

I m using this code but the above error keeps coming, don't know what to do next?

This is my code

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image

image_folder = sys.argv[0]
output_folder = sys.argv[1]

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
   os.makedirs(output_folder)

for filename in os.listdir(image_folder):
  img= Image.open(f'{image_folder}{filename}')
  img.save(f'{output_folder}{filename}','png')
  print('alldone!')
```

Comment: Please copy/paste exactly how you run this from the command line. The error lies in `image_folder = sys.argv[0]`. Print out `image_folder` and `output_folder` in your script to see what I mean

Comment: The first element in `sys.argv` (`sys.argv[0]`) is the path of the script, not a path of a directory

Comment: ``sys.argv[1]`` get's the first command line argument  where as ``sys.argv[0]`` get's the file name.

Comment: inspectorG4dget i tried but it says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "images.py", line 6, in <module>
    output_folder = sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element of your script arguments, `sys.argv[0]`, is the path of the file executed - `images.py` in your case.

Change:

```
image_folder = sys.argv[0]
output_folder = sys.argv[1]
```

To:

```
image_folder = sys.argv[1]
output_folder = sys.argv[2]
```

Comment: I tried this one but it says

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "images.py", line 6, in <module>
    output_folder = sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: When i run the above one it says

Comment: images.py image-playground/new/    #IT works but second one don't. @Gabip

Comment: @RishabhJain did you provide 2 arguments for the script as the code requires? please share how you run your script.

Comment: I ran it again through different technique it worked @Gabip

Comment: Although another  while running the code further i m shown this error:   "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'image-playground/.DS_Store'

Comment: @RishabhJain this error is unrelated to your original topic. Please consider asking it as another SO question.